# Marquee the text of UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` whose text is coming from server. The width of the button is fixed. What I want is, if the text of button exceeds the width of button, the text should be marquee within the button. If the text fits within the button width, there should be no marquee effect.

I followed some links ([one](http://lab11.com/blogs/How-to-create-a-marquee-text-for-an-iPhone-app.html), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369314/how-to-add-a-moving-text-in-iphone)) but I am still hung up on the issue. I tried to implement first link but with no success. The text is not moving.

Is that because I need to take button inside a `UIView` or moving of text can happen within a button?

Comment: Can you show us or explain more abut what you tried for the first link? The code looks like it would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webview for this work, load html as given below, u can use a condition for check text is more or less, use href to hyper link the text. This hyper link text when clicked webview delegate recognizes it.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

  <html>
      <body bgcolor=\"#0066CC\">
      <marquee>some test to marquee </marquee>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think that loading a UIWebview ONLY for the marquee is a bit heavy handed. It will probably work (haven't tried it) but it seems like a misuse of resources.

Comment: this will be easy and no need to maintain data in separate array, as we got the data, generate html and load that's it. And the delegate gives the touched element with href url...

Comment: easy != good, especially considering resource usage on a mobile platform. Yes, it would probably work, but that doesn't mean it is the best way to do it.

Comment: In the same way difficult!=Best. 
In case we are not using a webview then obviously we have to introduce the concept of animation plus a label for the text plus a view including it for the required purpose.
And in my solution we are just using a webview that loads an HTml string and also the advance of this is we can handle tapped content with the help of delegate methods. So, I think this is kinda simple and affordable. If you have any other option the please let me know.

Comment: I agree, difficult != best. The great thing is, the two links he provide give him all he needs to do this, but he won't tell us what problems he encounters when he tries them, otherwise we could help him. UIWebView is an incredible expensive solution for what is a simple animation.

Comment: ok.. can u pls explain me in which case its expensive/heavy.. can u give me some links..

Comment: Search google for "UIWebView memory" or "UIWebView overhead". Even better, try to implement what you suggested and tell us how the performance is. It will work, but it will not be anywhere near as smooth an experience as a CoreAnimation solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem i check your 2 link and 2nd one work in my case.
I am posting my code for you.

```
messageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 680, 635, 19)];
[messageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[backgroundImageView addSubview:messageView];
 lblTime = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(900, 680, 635, 19)];// your starting animation point 
[lblTime setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
lblTime.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[lblTime setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
[backgroundImageView addSubview:lblTime];
[self sendNotification:@"your message"]; // call the method


- (void)sendNotification:(NSString*)txt{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:8.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:messageView cache:YES];
[lblTime setText:txt];
[lblTime setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
lblTime.frame = CGRectMake(20, 680, 650, 19); // end point of animation
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```